# Totally not spam; don't delete me

Tags: lateral-thinking, password

Thanks for registering for our super-not-spam mailing list! We'll let you unsubscribe if you can find a super-special password!

Here are the criteria for the password:

- Matches the following regex expression: `\w.\w\w`
- Includes 3 digits, 1 special character/symbol, and 4 letters
- Contains the letter `r` and the numbers are between `0` and `5` (inclusive).
- The sum of the ASCII codes for the password is 631.
- The character in position 4 (zero-indexed) is not a lowercase letter.
- The special character is before all three digits.
- The digits add up to 10.
- Two of the digits are the same.
- The special character is between `!` and `#`.
- Exactly two of the lowercase letters and two of the digits are adjacent.

Password to unsubscribe: ________________________________

Can you find it? It will be obvious once you do. If you get a password that does not seem obvious, that's not the one you're looking for. Therefore, it might be helpful to write a program for this.

Comment: Just to clarify: "before" means "earlier in the password", but "between `!` and `#`" means in ASCII value? (And I take it it's _inclusive_?)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan -- Yes to the first question and ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ to the second.

Comment: Given that no part of the password can be even partially deduced from the clues, this puzzle depends entirely on guessing and OP's definition of "obvious". So not my favourite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably meant to be

> p@55W0rd

All of the conditions match, with "between ! and #" meaning

> between the keys on a standard english QWERTY layout

Comment: On my keyboard, pretty much _everything_ is "between" ! (at top left) and # (at bottom-ish right). Oh well.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan -- Oh man, I should have been more specific/considerate of that. Well, now I know for next time.

Comment: This is correct; nice job!

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Btw, not sure if it's a red herring or you didn't know: `\w` not only matches [a-zA-z], but [a-zA-z0-9_], meaning any substring except the one starting at @ in this puzzle will match. I assume it was meant for the `W0rd` substring

Comment: @LukasRotter -- I was aware of that. It does actually match the whole thing because of the `.` in there. It was meant to hint at the fact that the special character was either at position 1 or 5 (zero-indexed)

Comment: @vol . matches a single character, not any number of characters

Comment: @msh210 -- I'm aware of that too. `\w.\w\w` matches `p@55` and it matches `W0rd`, thus matching the whole thing.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Don't want to start a war here, but I think the crux here is our interpretation of "Matches the following regex expression". In my mind, this means "The regex produces one or more matches" (same as in e.g. the C# method IsMatch() and other, which is probably where I got that from), which would be the case for almost any combination of allowed inputs here. It also "doesn't match the whole thing" in my mind, since I count a "whole match" as "one regex produces exactly one match across the entire string," (obv not possible here), not "2 matches which cover the entire string"

Comment: @LukasRotter -- I agree, it's just a difference of interpretations. My goal of using that string was to show two things: 1. the length of the password is a multiple of 4 and 2. the position of the special character is either the second or fifth character.